# How to maintain HTML internal links when converting with Pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to convert from html to pdf with Pandoc. The output is pretty nice, still with the command `pandoc index.html -o output.pdf`I lose all my internal links (from table of contents to chapters, from text to footnotes, etc).

Is there any way to keep all the links also in the output?

Comment: Pandoc supports [internal links](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#internal-links) also for LaTeX, and ConTeXt. Have you changed the default LaTeX template?